# Import excel data from xls\xlsx file to another

Tags: java, excel, xlsx, xls, hssfworkbook

I have to make a small **java** aplication that allows the user to import an excel file (.xls.xlsx) with all the sheets and then the user must be able to export specific data from the imported excel file to a new file, displaying the selected data of only one sheet.
So far, I got the Import part working so is export part as well. (I'll insert the code bellow)

```
public class ModeloExcel {
 Workbook wb;

 public String Importar(File archivo, JTable tablaD){
    String respuesta="Import failed.";
    DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
    tablaD.setModel(modeloT);
    tablaD.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    try {
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));
        int nsheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
        //FOR para carregar todas as folhas
        for(int i = 0; i < nsheets; i++){
        Sheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        Iterator filaIterator = hoja.rowIterator();
        int indiceFila=-1;
        while (filaIterator.hasNext()) {                
            indiceFila++;
            Row fila = (Row) filaIterator.next();
            Iterator columnaIterator = fila.cellIterator();
            Object[] listaColumna = new Object[1000];
            int indiceColumna=-1;
            while (columnaIterator.hasNext()) {                    
                indiceColumna++;
                Cell celda = (Cell) columnaIterator.next();
                if(indiceFila==0){
                    modeloT.addColumn(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }else{
                    if(celda!=null){
                        switch(celda.getCellType()){
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getNumericCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getBooleanCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getErrorCellValue();
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                return null;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getCellFormula();
                            default:
                                listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getDateCellValue();
                                break;
                        }
                        System.out.println("col"+indiceColumna+" valor: true - "+celda+".");
                    }                        
                }
            }
            if(indiceFila!=0)modeloT.addRow(listaColumna);
        }
        respuesta="Imported with success";
        }//fim for
    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return respuesta;
}

public String Exportar(File archivo, JTable tablaD){
    String respuesta="Export failed";
    int numFila=tablaD.getRowCount(), numColumna=tablaD.getColumnCount();
    if(archivo.getName().endsWith("xls")){
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }else{
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }
    Sheet hoja = wb.createSheet("Hoja Principal");

    try {
        for (int i = -1; i < numFila; i++) {
            Row fila = hoja.createRow(i+1);
            for (int j = 0; j < numColumna; j++) {
                Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                if(i==-1){
                    celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tablaD.getColumnName(j)));
                }else{
                    celda.setCellValue(String.valueOf(tablaD.getValueAt(i, j)));
                }
                wb.write(new FileOutputStream(archivo));
            }
        }
        respuesta="Exported with success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

This is the ExcelModel class

```
public class ControladorExcel implements ActionListener{
ModeloExcel modeloE = new ModeloExcel();
VistaExcel vistaE= new VistaExcel();
JFileChooser selecArchivo = new JFileChooser();
File archivo;
int contAccion=0;

public ControladorExcel(VistaExcel vistaE, ModeloExcel modeloE){
    this.vistaE= vistaE;
    this.modeloE=modeloE;
    this.vistaE.btnImportar.addActionListener(this);
    this.vistaE.btnExportar.addActionListener(this);
}

public void AgregarFiltro(){
    selecArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel (*.xls)", "xls"));
    selecArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel (*.xlsx)", "xlsx"));
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    contAccion++;
    if(contAccion==1)AgregarFiltro();

    if(e.getSource() == vistaE.btnImportar){
        if(selecArchivo.showDialog(null, "Select Directory")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo=selecArchivo.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.getName().endsWith("xls") || archivo.getName().endsWith("xlsx")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        modeloE.Importar(archivo, vistaE.jtDatos) + "\n Formato ."+ archivo.getName().substring(archivo.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1), 
                        "IMPORTAR EXCEL", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose a valid format(xls/xlsx).");
            }
        }
    }

    if(e.getSource() == vistaE.btnExportar){
        if(selecArchivo.showDialog(null, "Exportar")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo=selecArchivo.getSelectedFile();
            if(archivo.getName().endsWith("xls") || archivo.getName().endsWith("xlsx")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, modeloE.Exportar(archivo, vistaE.jtDatos) + "\n Formato ."+ archivo.getName().substring(archivo.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1));
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose a valid format(xls/xlsx).");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is de ExcelController class

[This is the jFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbxp1.png)

So, the point is: the user must be able to select which columns from each sheet of the imported excel file to be exported to the new file. Bellow, I'll leave an example of what the excel files should look like:

[Import file - Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bnHQ.png)

[Import file - Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZalMu.png)

[Import file - Sheet3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L55Jt.png)

[Final Exported file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsJr7.png)

I'm using **NetBeans IDE** to develop this aplication, and as a new guy on this, is it possible to achieve this? If it is possible, how?

Comment: How does it help you if we answer "yes"?

Comment: yeah well, i edited the question, i forgot to mention "how?"